# [UIViewController setRecipeName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am(from java); new to objective c and xcode. Below is the code which is building fine but throwing `unrecognized selector sent to instance`. I tried to fix it by googling.. but no luck.

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"myAccSegue"]) {
    MyAccountController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSString *s = @"avcd";//[_carImages objectAtIndex: (NSUInteger)index.section ];
    destViewController.recipeName=s;
}
```

and MyAccountController is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyAccountController : UITableViewController

@property NSInteger index;

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *recipeName;

@end
```

in MyAccountController.m i wrote `@synthesise recipeName`. When i run i get the error

```
2013-06-29 23:02:28.962 abcd[9171:c07] -[UIViewController setRecipeName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7560cc0
```

A little debuggng shows ox7560cc0 belongs to `destinationViewController`. Not sure what has gone wrong..

Any help please?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error message

```
-[UIViewController setRecipeName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...
```

indicates that

```
MyAccountController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
```

did not return a `MyAccountController` as expected, but a `UIViewController`.

A probable reason is that you did not set the "Custom Class" of the view controller to "MyAccountController" in the storyboard file.