# I can't understand what the problem with the Navigator Controller

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uistoryboardsegue

I have just started working with **Xcode**(I use Xcode 15.0.1) and wanted to create a small app to understand transitions between **ViewControllers**. Following the code from an online video, I encountered an error. I tried to solve the issue myself and used different ways to write the same action. However, I kept getting the same error every time.
I wanted to make it so that from the **BlueViewController**, when I press the 'Orange' button, there would be a transition to the **OrangeViewController** using a **Navigation Controller**.
This is the code in **BlueViewController**.

```swift
@IBAction func ShowOrangeViewController(_ sender: Any) {
        let orangeVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OrangeViewController") as! OrangeViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(orangeVC, animated: true);
    }
    
}
```

This is what Main looks like.

[image: Screens]

When I run the program and press the Orange button, it triggers an error.

```
Thread 1: "-[UIViewController ShowOrangeViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x103b06a2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unrecognized selector sent to instance, Storyboard bug after connecting a button to view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287464/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-storyboard-bug-after-connecting-a-button)

Comment: @Confuseious That has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[UIViewController setRecipeName:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382957/uiviewcontroller-setrecipename-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the error you are getting, it says the IBAction it can't find is `-[UIViewController ShowOrangeViewController:]:`.

---

### Edit:

I created a [**project with your setup**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/PushFromButton.git), got it working, and then commented out my IBAction in my BlueViewController. The error I got was "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PushFromButton.BlueViewController handleOrangeButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102907fb0'"

Note that it lists the target object as `BlueViewController`, not `UIViewController`. (That is the class name for my Blue view controller. `PushFromButton` is the name of the app.) Your error says the target is `UIViewController`, a generic view controller.

---

It's trying to find your `ShowOrangeViewController(_:)` method in the base `UIViewController` class. Your "Blue View Controller" is probably of a custom class "BlueViewController", but the IBAction is trying to invoke the method in the wrong class.

Do these things:

- Open your storyboard and select the "View Controller Scene" for the blue view controller. Then select the "identity inspector" and make sure the class of that view controller shows as "BlueViewController" (or whatever class name you gave your blue view controller.)
- Switch to the Connections Inspector, select the "Orange" button in your Blue View controller, and check the IBAction for the button.

I'm guessing it says "UIViewController ShowOrangeViewController", which is wrong. If so:

- Click the x in the connections inspector under the events for the orange button to remove the bad IBAction link.
- Option-click on your "OrangeViewController.swift" source file to open it in the auxiliary editor.
- Control-drag from the orange button in the Interface builder onto your `ShowOrangeViewController` action and make sure it creates a link and now lists that IBAction correctly.

Re-run your program and try the orange button again.

### Edit:

By the way, there are some strong naming conventions in Swift that you should learn to follow. One of those conventions is that function names and variable names should start with a lower-case letter. Only type names should start with a lower-case letter. Thus, your IBAction should be named `showOrangeViewController(_:)`, not `ShowOrangeViewController`.

If you select the name "ShowOrangeViewController" in the BlueViewController's source file, then select "refactor>rename" from the editor menu, Xcode will do a smart rename of your IBAction, including any code that calls that method **and** fixing the link in your storyboard to use the new name.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. But my BlueViewController has the class "BlueViewController," and the same goes for OrangeViewController. I have also set the same (like "BlueViewController" and "OrangeViewController") Storyboard ID for them. Also the IBAction for "Orange" button says "Blue View Controller ShowOrangeViewController":

Comment: Try breaking and reconnecting the IBAction.

Comment: And make sure you don't have more than one IBAction. Buttons can be connected to more than one IBAction.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is. I've reconnect the IBAction, and this is the only one IBAction I have.

Comment: Upload your project to Github and post a link in your question.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/minrika/swiftProdjekt.git )  I'm new to this, and I hope it was done correctly.

Comment: No, you posted a zip of the project file. You want to add a remote to the git project that Xcode creates for you, and then commit and push your project.

Comment: I created a project on Github that does what you show in your question. You can download it at this link: https://github.com/DuncanMC/PushFromButton.git

Comment: Thank you very much for your project. I still don't understand why the problem is with mine but now I can compare my code with yours.(I didn't give any marks)

Comment: You should learn how to upload projects to GitHub. Assuming that when you create your project, you leave the "Create Git repository on my Mac" checkbox checked, it's quite simple. Go to your Github account, tap "New" to create an empty repository, and enter your project name as the name of the repo. Once you've done that, in the "quick setup" box, select "SSH" and copy the git url for your repo into the clipboard. Then go to Xcode, open your project, select editor>Add Existing Remote, and add a remote and paste the URL from Github into the URL field. Finally commit and push your project.

Comment: (I use SourceTree to manage my repos since Xcode's source management is awful. I haven't done what I describe above in Xcode very often.)